# ioredis allowing to create repeated keys

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

Trying to **LOCK** key for a scheduler, but `ioredis` is allowing me to create multiple keys with same name.

```
import * as redis from '../redis'

const redCli = redis.get(); // get function that starts ioredis

scheduleJob('my-job', '*/05 * * * * *', async () => {
  const key = await redCli.set('my-key', 'key-value', 'EX', 30); // 30 seconds key lifetime  
  console.log(`KEY: ${key}`); // always log 'OK'

  if (!key) {
  // log error and return. NEVER gets here.
  } 

  // ALSO TRIED:
  if (redCli.exists('my-key')...
  if (await redCli.ttl('my-key')...


  // continue the flow...
});
```

I create a key with 30 seconds of lifetime. And my scheduler runs every 5 seconds.
When I try to `redCli.set()` a key that already exists, [shouldn't](https://github.com/luin/ioredis/blob/main/examples/ttl.js) return an ERROR/FALSE? Anything but 'OK'...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why my attempts didn't work, but I solved this using `get`

```
const cachedKey = await redisClient.get('my-key');

if(cachedKey) { 
  // Key Already Exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like most mutating commands in Redis, the SET command in Redis is an upsert. That's just how Redis works.

From the [docs](https://redis.io/commands/set/) for the SET command:

> If key already holds a value, it is overwritten, regardless of its type. Any previous time to live associated with the key is discarded on successful SET operation.